# Python: Map a string value from one dataframe to another dataframe using a id, while creating a new column in the older dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i turned a json file into a dataframe,  but I am unsure of how to map a certain value from the json dataframe onto the existing data frame i have.

```
df1 =     # (2nd column does'nt matter just there)
```

| category_id | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 10 | b |
| 10 | c |
| 40 | d |

```
df2(json) =
```

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | film |
| 2 | music |
| 3 | travel |
| 4 | cooking |
| 5 | dance |

I would like to make a new column in df1, that maps the titles from the df2 onto df1 corresponding to the category_id. I am sorry I am new to python programming. I know I can hard code the dictionary and key values and go from there. However I was wondering if there is a way with python/pandas to do this in an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) which maps values of Series according to input correspondence.

```py
df1['tilte'] = df1['category_id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['title'])
```

```
# print(df1)

   category_id tags tilte
0            1    a  film
1            1    a  film
2           10    b   NaN
3           10    c   NaN
4           40    d   NaN
```

Comment: thank you very much! this helped out so much